# PTIJ: Why do we announce that there is mold in shul only on the Shabbat before Rosh Hodesh?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I located [this article](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol%206%20Loewinger.pdf) entitled:

על הכרזת המולד בבתי הכנסת

Regarding the announcement of mold in the shul

The first paragraph says that it is common in Ashkenazi shuls to announce on Shabbat *Mevarchim Hachodesh* (Shabat preceding new month) that there is mold in the shul.

Having mold in your shul is not excatly healthy. If someone knew about an abundance of mold in the shul, wouldn't you want to know about it, or, maybe close the shul until it's disinfected?

Why wait until the Shabbat before Rosh Hodesh to inform people about the shul mold? What's special about that time?

And, why is this common in Ashkenazi shuls? Don't Sefardi shuls announce about mold, or maybe they don't wait until just before Rosh Hodesh to do so?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 4):

The reason Ashkenazim only announce mold in shuls on the Shabbat before Rosh Chodesh is linked to the minhag of only performing the Birkhat Cohenim on Yom Tov. Cohenim are responsible for removing shul tzarrat, but are only permitted to do so after giving Am Yisrael their blessing. Since many Sephardic communities in chutz l'aaretz perform the Birkhat Cohenim at least twice a week, shul tzarrat doesn't get a chance to build up.

Comment: I know that you are Sephardi. I assume that you are also a Cohen?

Comment: @DanF my father's family hails from Hungary but yes I daven Sephardi. We are indeed Cohenim ;)

Comment: In many shuls it is the rabbi who blesses the new month, some only turn up for that, so he is the one to bless the mold should disappear, I am sure it is in one of the blessings especially the sefardi nusach which is a lot longer than the ashkenazi one but I havent yet worked out which. I may add he is always successful the mold (moon) has never not disappeared.